# Compare 2 columns in a csv/excel sheet and do something with them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate 2 columns but only if they do not have the same value in them.

EXAMPLE

```
Col1     Col2
A        A
A        B
B        B
A        B
B        B
```

I used this to compare the 2 columns:

```
df['compare'] = np.where(df[col1].fillna('') == df[col2].fillna(''), 0, 1
```

Output of the 3 columns now is:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3
A        A        0
A        B        1
B        B        0
A        B        1
B        B        0
```

Now I am trying to use this to concatenate the 2 fields if col3 = 1

```
if df[col3] == '1':
   df[col4] = df[col1].fillna('') + df[col2].fillna('')
else:
   df[col4] = df[col1].fillna('')
```

I keep getting a Truth value of a series is ambiguous error.

What I am looking for in the end would be

```
Col1     Col2      col4
A        A         A
A        B         AB
B        B         B
A        B         AB
B        B         B
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df['Col4'] = df[['Col1', 'Col2']].agg(lambda x: ''.join(np.unique(x)), axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
  Col1 Col2 Col4
0    A    A    A
1    A    B   AB
2    B    B    B
3    A    B   AB
4    B    B    B
```

Another ways:

```
df['Col4'] = df['Col1'].mask(df['Col1'] != df['Col2'], other=df['Col1'] + df['Col2'])

df['Col4'] = np.where(df['Col1'] != df['Col2'], df['Col1']+df['Col2'], df['Col1'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict.fromkeys to keep unique values and join:

```
df[['Col1', 'Col2']].apply(dict.fromkeys, axis=1).str.join('')
```